# Does there exist a Web-based office suite, not in the cloud?

Tags: self-hosted, office-online

Are there any collaborative web-based office suites that I could install on my own server? Something like Google Docs, without storing data on Google.

I need at least a basic word processor and a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 4):

There's [Feng Office](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opengoo/files/) (community edition is self hosted). I've been playing with it and it's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the spreadsheet but you could use [Etherpad](http://etherpad.org/) for the document collaboration.

> Etherpad ... allows really real-time document collaboration for groups of users. Etherpad is open source; you can host your own Etherpad by downloading the source code or try Etherpad for free on one of the Public Sites.

Hope this helps.